# Prism, accessing DryIoC container from AppDelegate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, dryioc, prism-7

I want to access the IoC Container from the FinishedLoading and the RegisteredForRemoteNotifications/OpenUrl functions in the App Delegate, is this possible?

I tried to access the container after the App was initialised in the Finishedloading function but it throws an error saying it's unable to resolve.

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        var iosApp = new App(new iOSInitializer());

        LoadApplication(iosApp);

        var container = iosApp.Container;

        _appModel = container.Resolve<IAppModel>();
        _configuration = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
        _notificationService = container.Resolve<INotificationService>();

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

Comment: `it throws an error saying it's unable to resolve` that's intentional to prevent people from light-heartedly making what is most of the times a grave mistake (using the container anywhere but at the resolution root).

Comment: there's actually no reason that shouldn't work... completely different story as to whether or not it's really something you should be doing... @Jjohnny can you provide more context as to what the error is that you're getting

Answer (score 0):

Adding DryIoc namespace worked for me.

```
using DryIoc;
```